# Ubuntu software application shows icons and software brand, but no description

Tags: software-center

I'm trying to use Ubuntu and now I explore the "Ubuntu Software" which is similar to google's play market (as I understand). I'm trying to explore available software, but got only icons and very short titles (like "knowte" - what it could be?), and it's obviously doesn't leave me a chance to select anything because such short titles and an icon just do not provide almost any information about the software.

I know that I can click on an application and read details there, but I see no point in clicking, waiting for loading and finally reading hundreds of pages when I just want something like notepad.

Where can I obtain just a plain list of software descriptions? Then I'll be able to glance at the list and filter applications relatively quickly. And some search features, of course, could be very useful, but such obvious thing is also missing.

My version of Ubuntu is 20.04. I just installed it and trying to use for browsing and other simple tasks.

Answer (score 0):

"Just a plain list" would include *tens of thousands* of packages for you to sift through. So that approach seems inefficient.

Something like Notepad is already included with Ubuntu - Gedit. It's quite good.

But on to your question. Here's how to find software in Ubuntu...

Take a look at the top-left corner of Ubuntu Software. Look for the Search icon. Click it.

[image]

Let's Search for "Notepad" and see the kinds of results we get...

[image]